# How to change URL from JSON parsing

Tags: android, json

hi guys i am making an Android app which enlarge the Instagram profile pictures 
i have done everything correctly now what i want is to modifiy the output url that i am getting from instagram server for example when i run my json script it give me this

https://instagram.fkhi6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-19/s320x320/20766978_110444579680760_4754914132547862528_a.jpg

and i want to convert this to that

https://instagram.fkhi6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-19/s800x800/20766978_110444579680760_4754914132547862528_a.jpg

here is my code that i am using

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, finalURL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject user = response.getJSONObject("user");
                        String profilePicture = user.getString("profile_pic_url_hd");


                      Log.v("JSON", "User: " + profilePicture);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.v("FUN", "Error " + error.toString());


                }
            });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried usual string replace? :) kind of `profilePicture.replace("s320x320", "s800x800")` ?

Comment: I'd add a small change to @xAqweRx comment: `profilePicture.replace("/s320x320/", "/s800x800/")` just to make sure that the hash collision with `s320x320` will not happen.

Comment: guys its not doing anything even with profilePicture.replace("/s320x320/", "/s800x800/") output is still same @VladMatvienko

Comment: did you assign new value, didn't you? `profilePicture = profilePicture.replace("/s320x320/", "/s800x800/")'`

Comment: Now its working :D i am just wondering now how to download that image that i have just fetched if u know then please do tell me :D @VladMatvienko

Comment: google knows for sure. Please search before asking. Search for `android imageview from url`

Comment: Thank You :D @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String imageUrl=originalUrl.replaceAll("[s][0-9]+[x][0-9]+","s"+desiredWidth+"x"+desiredHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it works:

```
String smallImageUrl = "https://instagram.fkhi6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-19/s320x320/20766978_110444579680760_4754914132547862528_a.jpg";
String largeImageURL = smallImageUrl.replace("s320x320", "s800x800");
```